# Why doesn't my Python Tkinter Button show up

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, tkinter, widget

I was recently learning about Tkinter and I wanted to try building an online program that allows people to create documents and edit them or create them in a Tkinter window. However, my code for some reason does not show the Tkinter Button that is supposed to save and write to the file. Forget the editing docs part, I want to first work out this kink.

```
from tkinter import *
action = input("Do you want to create or edit a doc? c for create, e for edit:\n").lower()

if action == 'c':
  name = input("What do you want to name your document? ").lower()
  fs = open(name + ".txt", 'w')
  txtData = ""
  tab = Tk()
  tab.geometry('500x400')
  tab.resizable(0,0)
  inputTxt = Text(tab, width = 200, height = 100, padx = 30, pady = 30)
  inputTxt.pack()
  def save():
    inputTxtGet = inputTxt.get(1.0, 'end-1c')
    txtData = inputTxtGet
    fs.write(txtData)
    fs.close()
  saveBtn = Button(tab, text = "Write and Save", command = save, background = "green", activebackground = "lime").pack()
```

I don't understand what is going wrong, as no error comes up. Help me debug this please.

Comment: Note that the `width` and `height` of a `Text` widget are *characters* and *lines* respectively, so the text box `inputTxt` is too big (200 characters wide and *100 lines* tall) for a window of size `500x400` (in pixels).

Comment: Oh, thanks. Didn't know that. I thought it was all pixels.

Comment: @ProgramProdigy You are mixing up command line commands like `input` and tkinter widgets. This is generally a bad idea. Rather than expecting the user to enter the name of the document, why not do what pretty much every GUI does and bring up a save dialog box? And to create or edit, why not have New/Open options in a menu bar at the top of the application.

Comment: @scotty3785 I don't know enough about Tkinter to do that, but if you could send a tutorial on how to do that, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

> However, my code for some reason does not show the Tkinter Button that
> is supposed to save and write to the file. Forget the editing docs
> part, I want to first work out this kink.

tab object must start at the top.

Move `Button` and `Entry` widget outside of function.

Snippet re-wrote:

```
from tkinter import *

tab = Tk()
tab.geometry('500x400')
   

action = input("Do you want to create or edit a doc? c for create, e for edit:\n").lower()

if action == 'c':
  name = input("What do you want to name your document? ").lower()
  fs = open(name + ".txt", 'w')
  txtData = ""
   
   
def save():
    inputTxtGet = inputTxt.get(1.0, 'end-1c')
    txtData = inputTxtGet
    fs.write(txtData)
    fs.close()
    
saveBtn = Button(tab, text = "Write and Save", command = save, background = "green", activebackground = "lime").pack()
inputTxt = Text(tab, width = 200, height = 100, padx = 30, pady = 30)
inputTxt.pack()


tab.mainloop()
```

Screenshot after getting input from user:

[image]